# How to partially ftp a file (using ftp, wget with shell scripts or php)?

Tags: php, shell, ftp, wget

i want to partially download a ftp file. i just need to download lets say 10MB, but after skipping 100MB (for example).

In php, http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-fget.php this function allows arbitay starting point:

```
bool ftp_fget  (  resource $ftp_stream  ,  resource $handle  ,  string $remote_file  ,  int $mode  [,  int $resumepos = 0  ] )
```

however it does not allow me to set "how many bytes" i want to download.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to open an FTP connection using a [stream wrapper](https://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.ftp.php) instead of the FTP functions (assuming you know the path to the file).

```
$fh = fopen('ftp://user:password@example.com/pub/file.txt', 'r');
```

Then just use normal file functions to open the file and read the information you want. You can't use `fseek()`, but `fread()` should work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the `--range` option to  [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/) to retrieve a range of bytes from a remote file.

If you have the `curl` command line tool installed you can run it from PHP using `shell_exec()` this way:

```
$bytes3to4 = shell_exec("curl --range 3-4 ftp://ftp.example.com/pub/file.txt");
```

Or if the cURL extension is available you can use it directly from PHP:

```
$ch = curl_init("ftp://ftp.example.com/pub/file.txt");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RANGE, "3-4");  // fetch bytes 3 to 4
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

$bytes3to4 = curl_exec($ch);
```

See [the cURL manual](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-r) for details